# A man on a hill

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

A man walks up a hill at 2mph, and back down the same way at 4mph. Upon returning to where he started, what is his average speed?

Comment: I vote to close this question as math problem

Comment: And the answer is 2.67 mph...if someone is wondering..

Comment: Answered, and voted to close.

Comment: So should this be posted on the Mathematics StackExchange? Seems a bit trivial for that site, given the complexity of some of the topics covered there.

Comment: It is not an intuitive result, so I would agree that this is still a puzzle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is :

> $\frac{8}{3}$ mph

Let's take the distance up (and down) the hill as $d$.

Then,

> Time taken in reaching top of the hill is : $\frac{d}{2}$

And

> Time taken in coming down the hill is : $\frac{d}{4}$

Thus, average speed is: $\frac{total  \space distance}{total \space time \space taken}$.

which is:

> $\frac{d+d}{\frac{d}{2}+\frac{d}{4}}$

On simplifying,

> it gives $\frac{8}{3}$ or $2.67$ mph (approx).